# PHP shell_exec inconsistent

Tags: php, macos, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to search through PDF files for multiple key words. I've got ~60 PDFs and ~8 key words and don't fancy ~480 manual searches.

I'm open for other suggestions (see below), but at present my approach is to use `mdfind` on OS X, like this:

```
$finds = array();
foreach ($search as $term) {
    $result = "";
    $cleanResult = array();
    $shellQuery = "mdfind -onlyin \"$wd\" \"kind:pdf $term\"";
    echo "\n\n$shellQuery\n";
    $result = shell_exec($shellQuery);
    echo $result;
    $cleanResult = split("\n", $result);
    array_pop($cleanResult);
    $finds[$term] = $cleanResult;

    unset($result);
    unset($cleanResult);
}
print_r($finds);
```

However, although this builds `$shellQuery` just fine, for some reason `$result` doesn't always get populated even when the command works (i.e. if I copy and paste the value of `$shellQuery` into a terminal window, it works as expected).

Let's say `$search` contains 'foo', 'bar' and 'joe', it might find 'foo' and 'joe' fine, but return nothing for 'bar'. If I remove 'foo' and 'joe' from the array and just search for 'bar', it'll find 'bar' fine. Does it need a rest between calls or something?!

Incidentally, my preferred approach would be to do something like:

`find . -name "*.pdf*" -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep -i -l "foo"`

but I can't get this to work in Terminal. I've installed http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/packages/ (I struggle to compile things, so packages like this = thumbs up!), but every time I try and pipe this to grep (e.g. `pdftotext myfile.pdf - | grep -i -l "foo"`) grep just returns `(standard output)` and no more.

Comment: Is there any way you can rewrite your question? Use less words, please. I find it very difficult to parse.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith There's nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: I prefer using `exec()` because it also captures the return value; maybe the tool returned an error. You could also redirect standard error using `2>&1`.

Comment: Thanks Jack -- exec doesn't work either unfortunately; still returning nothing.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith sorry you don't find it readable. Simply: `shell_exec` isn't returning something even though the exact same command passed to it does return something when used in Terminal.

Comment: Update: if I run the same (valid) command twice in a row, the first time it returns something fine, but the second time it doesn't return anything!

Comment: I would suggest using a search engine for your application if you can do it.... look at Apache Solr.